# Firebase authentication error "The given sign-in provider is disabled"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

**SOLVED**

I am trying to put authentication on firebase. I finish my code, and, when I tried it, it says:

> The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

I tried to search on YouTube and Google. But I didn´t find anything.

Comment: I'm able to login to your app What is the problem you are having Joseph?? You can check the authentication Section having my Email `tmadhuker` signed in using `google`

Comment: That's the Email sign-in method, he's confusing that with the Google sign-in method with mandates the OAuth redirect instead of plain forms.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The message is telling you exactly what to do, go to the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) of your project and turn the corresponding auth methods on. If you are only trying to use Gmail (Google) login, then just enable Google in the sign-in methods inside the Authentication tab, like this:

[image]

Also, make sure that you only put the sign-in options that you needed and turned on inside the `siginOptions` parameter, if Google is the only one you want, then just put `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` and remove everything else.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190727/discussion-on-answer-by-jackz314-firebase-authentication-error-the-given-sign-i).

Comment: Do I have to sign in to Google in order to use Google Drive?

Comment: I mean, I only want to upload/download files from there, do I still have to enable Google Sign in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Google Drive APIs, you should look that up yourself or open another question about it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but this doesn't help. @Jack It just won't work. Of course I enabled it in console. That's a basic thing

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled a bit with this one as the checkbox in Firebase for the Email link (passwordless sign-in) was 100% selected and my project configuration the right one, but I was still getting errors.

The issue in my case was that I was using several tenants in Cloud Identity, and the settings for each tenant did not inherit from the global ones.

So for each tenant, click the edit pencil and check whether the settings are the ones you are looking for.

[image: tenant]

[image: tenant settings]

Answer (score 1):

Already there are great answers in this thread, I'll share my experience also. You'll get the same error message if you have restricted SMS regions ( in the case of phone auth) and your user tries to login from a restricted region.

You can check if you have any restricted SMS regions under Authentication -> Settings tab in firebase console

[image: check if you got any restricted regions inside authentication setting in firebase console]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is telling you that you are trying to use auth firebase service but you have not enable it from firebase, SO please visit to firebase console of your peoject and enable may be it will be phone, gmail, email password or any else just enable it.like this image added below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PODi0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Message says clearly that you need to enable E-Mail as a Sign-in Method in the Firebase Console. Under Authentication, click on "Sign-in method".

[image]

After that click on the edit Icon on the right on the E-Mail Sign-in method.
[image]
Now you need to enable the second check box to allow Sign-up with E-Mail Link.