# Trying to use Google Firebase Authentication with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

We're using Firebases authentication for logging in and registering accounts. For some reason, one person on the team (member 1) is able to use it properly but when myself or another team member (member 3) tries to test it by creating an account or logging in we get the error

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: The given sign-in
> provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the
> Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

We have tried everything we can think of to fix this error. Email/password sign-in is enabled in the firebase project. We've tried completely copying the files on his machine to ours and it still won't work. What's even odder is that it works fine on member 3's laptop, but not his desktop. I've also had member 1 send me a build from his machine onto my phone and it will work then. I tried completely reinstalling Android Studio as well. I'm not even sure what files to show because I can't imagine it's a problem with the code, since it works perfectly fine for member 1 and member 3 on his laptop. If there's any file you need to see I'll be glad to add it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase authentication error "The given sign-in provider is disabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327973/firebase-authentication-error-the-given-sign-in-provider-is-disabled)

Comment: @siamsot No, I've already tried that. I've triple checked that email/password sign-in is enabled so it's not that. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

That might actually be working in the third members laptop because he would have linked the firebase with your project and put the SHA-1 of his laptop, If you want that to work with yours as well then you need to go to firebase console and add SHA-1 to the console to have it work. [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/13167993).

And if it helps please do accept i, if I didnt help let me know and il check more for you.

Comment: It didn't seem to work, It already had that SHA-1 key in the firebase console.